# How to parse the profile object from a Yahoo oAuth2 result?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I'm not understanding something about the profile information I am getting from a Yahoo authentication. Specifically, I want to get the email address from the "emails" property.

The "emails" property is an array. When I try to iterate over the array or parse it as I would any other array, I run into a snag:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/content/54/7550554/html/talqo/youath2callback.php on line 33
```

Here is the code in my oauth callback page, up until the line where the error happens:

```
require("lib/Yahoo.inc");  

// Your Consumer Key (API Key) goes here. 
define('CONSUMER_KEY', "$consumer_key");  

// Your Consumer Secret goes here.  
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', "$consumer_secret");  

// Your application ID goes here.  
define('APPID', "$appId");  

$session = YahooSession::requireSession(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,APPID);  

// Fetch the logged-in (sessioned) user  
$user = $session->getSessionedUser();  

// Fetch the profile for the current user.  
$profile = $user->getProfile();

foreach($profile as $k => $v ){
    echo "$k = $v <br>";
}
```

The output of the foreach group make sense, until it hits some value that is throwing the error:

```
uri = http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/IRSAJKSJHGAH3OMPDQSQ7RIWV4/profile
guid = IRSAJKSJHGAH3OMPDQSQ7RIWV4
birthdate = 5/13
created = 2012-09-11T13:47:38Z
emails = Array
familyName = Last NameLewis
gender = M
givenName = Gregory

Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/content/54/7550554/html/talqo/youath2callback.php on line 33
```

If I `var_dump( $profile );` I get the whole package. I don't know if you want to see it, and I don't know if it's important to this question. It looks like my foreach loop hangs on ["image"]:

```
object(stdClass)#9 (17) { ["uri"]=> string(70) "http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/IRSAJKSJHGAH3OMPDQSQ7RIWV4/profile" ["guid"]=> string(26) "IRSAJKSJHGAH3OMPDQSQ7RIWV4" ["birthdate"]=> string(4) "5/30" ["created"]=> string(20) "2012-09-11T13:47:38Z" ["emails"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#11 (3) { ["handle"]=> string(27) "primaremail@mydomain.com" ["id"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> string(4) "HOME" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#12 (4) { ["handle"]=> string(20) "secondemail@yahoo.com" ["id"]=> int(2) ["primary"]=> bool(true) ["type"]=> string(4) "HOME" } } ["familyName"]=> string(14) "Last NameLewis" ["gender"]=> string(1) "M" ["givenName"]=> string(7) "Gregory" ["image"]=> object(stdClass)#13 (4) { ["height"]=> int(192) ["imageUrl"]=> string(55) "http://l.yimg.com/dh/ap/social/profile/profile_b192.png" ["size"]=> string(7) "192x192" ["width"]=> int(192) } ["lang"]=> string(5) "en-US" ["memberSince"]=> string(20) "2012-09-11T13:19:09Z" ["nickname"]=> string(7) "Gregory" ["phones"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#14 (3) { ["id"]=> int(5) ["number"]=> string(12) "1-1234567890" ["type"]=> string(6) "MOBILE" } } ["profileUrl"]=> string(51) "http://profile.yahoo.com/IRSAJKSJHGAH3OMPDQSQ7RIWV4" ["timeZone"]=> string(19) "America/Los_Angeles" ["updated"]=> string(20) "2013-06-13T14:59:34Z" ["isConnected"]=> bool(false) }
```

So, I guess my method of parsing this array isn't working for me.

If I try to echo the email, like so: `echo $profile->emails;` it just prints the word **Array**.

If I try to loop through the array, like so:

```
foreach($profile->emails as $k){
echo "$k <br>";
}
```

I get the error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/content/54/7550554/html/talqo/youath2callback.php on line 34
```

So, how do I properly convert all of the variables and objects and properties and whatnot in the Yahoo result to PHP variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't echo out the array objects. The issue here is that your `emails` key has an array of objects, when you try to echo them, PHP is unsuccessfully trying to convert those objects to strings.

If you need the email data you need to access them in an appropriate way like this:

```
foreach($profile->emails as $k){
   echo 'handle: ' . $k->handle . ' id: ' . $k->id . ' type: ' . $k->type . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: +1 for the answer, you know how to get only the user email who logged in ? not all emails. thanks in advance.

Comment: i done exact code but i got this error `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$handle in myfile.php` just after it it printed one id 3 and type HOME but handle is empty . any idea ?

Comment: i dont know if im using oauth1 or 2 if this plays a role

Comment: @echo_Me I am not fully familiar with this API, but it seems the `getSessionedUser()` call gets the information for the logged in user.  Now when you call `getProfile()` on the user that is returned there could be multiple emails related to that logged in user.

Comment: @MikeBrant what should i do with `getSessionedUser()` ?

Comment: @echo_Me I don't know.  What are you trying to do with it?  If you want the emails associated with the user, it seems you could follow the example above and call `getProfile()` and then access the email array at the `emails` property of the returned object.

Comment: i have done exactly as you done . and all worked (id and type) only this get error from it `$k->handle` , why `handle` i get error from it ?